# Express sessionID changes on every client's request

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, express-session

**My problem:**
When I go to server adress (so I'm using get method) it is working as I would want it to work, the sessionID doesn't change upon HTTP requests, but when I'm using client's `fetch` method to get to the server adress, the sessionID always changes and that is defect, what I don't want.

Any ideas why this is happening and how could I fix it?

**Code of how my sessions are set up:**

```
const session = require('express-session');

...

app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
      secure: false,
      sameSite: true,
    },
  })
);

...

app.get("/lobby/:id", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.sessionID);
  req.session.test = 1;
});
```

**Client's request**

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(getServerAdress() + "/lobby/" + code, {
    method: "GET",
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => setLoading(false))
    .catch(() => setLoadingText("Failed to join the lobby"));
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);
```

Comment: Fetch won't send cookies for [cross origin by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included)

Comment: Oh, thank you. I added credentials option to the fetch method and I support CORS on my server with credentials now and it works as I want it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mat J. said, fetch does not send cookies for cross-origin by default, so I had to change it:

```
fetch(getServerAdress() + "/lobby/" + code, {
    method: "GET",
    credentials: "include",
}
```

Also I had to enable credentials and origin for CORS on my server:

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));
```

Comment: Adding {credentials: 'include'} to my fetch options fixed the problem for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, just maybe, you or your customers are browsing the site in the Private mode of Chrome or Firefox. I followed all the steps on the internet, spent more than a few hours, and finally just switched to normal browsing. That solved the problem.